# Combine only different rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data.frames similar to these:

```
#Dt1
Id  Date Weight  
1    2     10
2    3     20
3    4     30
4    4     30
5    6     40
```

and

```
#DT2
Id  Date Weight late 
1    2     10     3
2    3     20     4
3    4     30     5
8    5     10     6
```

I would like to merge these files considering only the different ID between them like this:

```
#Dt.final
Id  Date Weight late
4    4     30    NA
5    6     40    NA
8    5     10     6
```

My originals files are bigger than these, thanks.

Comment: Don't work. @user1945827

Comment: You're going to run into problems with the differing number of columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df1 <- data.frame(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  Date = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 6),
                  Weight = c(10, 20, 30, 30, 40))

df2 <- data.frame(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 8),
                  Date = c(2, 3, 4, 5),
                  Weight = c(10, 20, 30, 10),
                  late = c(3, 4, 5, 6))

full_join(x = filter(.data = df1, Id %in% setdiff(x = df1$Id, y = df2$Id)),
          y = filter(.data = df2, Id %in% setdiff(x = df2$Id, y = df1$Id)))
#> Joining, by = c("Id", "Date", "Weight")
#>   Id Date Weight late
#> 1  4    4     30   NA
#> 2  5    6     40   NA
#> 3  8    5     10    6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

besides @yarnabrina answer, The `anti_join` in `dplyr` is also what you need, but we have to apply twice. `anti_join(x, y)` drops all obs in `x` that have a match in `y`:

```
> full_join(anti_join(df1, df2, by = 'Id'), anti_join(df2, df1, by = 'Id'))
Joining, by = c("Id", "Date", "Weight")
  Id Date Weight late
1  4    4     30   NA
2  5    6     40   NA
3  8    5     10    6
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can solve your problem, it is an hand made answer but I hope not too bad :

```
df_1 <- data.frame(ID = factor(1:5, levels=1:8),
                   Date = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 6),
                   Weight = c(10, 20, 20, 30, 40))

df_2 <- data.frame(ID = factor(4:8, levels=1:8),
                   Date = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 6),
                   Weight = c(10, 20, 20, 30, 40),
                   late = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

# Temporary dataframe
df_temp <- data.frame(
  df_1[!df_1$ID %in% df_2$ID, ],
  late = NA)

df.final <- rbind(
  df_temp,
  df_2[!df_2$ID %in% df_1$ID, ])
```

Comment: It doesn't generate the output OP wants.

Comment: Ok, it is not exactly the same input. Thanks for your answer using dplyr.